# VB.NET Add TabPage with Indexed Label

Tags: vb.net, loops, tabpage

**What are you trying to accomplish?**

I want to add a TabPage to a pre-existing TabControl with a Label that has an indexed name.

```
    Private Sub BtnAddReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddReport.Click

    Dim rep As New OpenFileDialog
    rep.Title = "Add Report"
    rep.InitialDirectory = "C:\Customers"
    rep.FileName = ""
    rep.DefaultExt = ".html"
    rep.Filter = "HTML Documents|*.html"
    rep.Multiselect = False
    If rep.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim newTab As TabPage = New TabPage With {.Text = Path.GetFileName(rep.FileName)}
        TabControl2.Controls.Add(newTab)

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To TabControl2.TabPages.Count
            Dim lbl As Label = New Label With {.Text = "Label" & i, .Location = New Point(3, 3)}
            newTab.Controls.Add(lbl)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

**What do you expect the result to be?**

Each time the button is clicked, a new tab is added with a label named "Label1", "Label2", etc.

**What is the actual result you get?**

This code creates a new tabpage and adds the label, but it's always named Label1 and does not increase by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a `For` loop in there?  You only want to add one `Label`, right?  You should be creating one `TabPage`, creating one `Label`, adding the `Label` to the `TabPage`, then adding the `TabPage` to the `TabControl`.

```
Dim newTab As TabPage = New TabPage With {.Text = Path.GetFileName(rep.FileName)}
Dim lbl As Label = New Label With {.Text = "Label" & (TabControl2.TabPages.Count + 1), .Location = New Point(3, 3)}

newTab.Controls.Add(lbl)
TabControl2.TabPages.Add(newTab)
```

Comment: Wow, I was vastly overthinking that. Getting rid of the For loop and doing what you said worked perfectly. Thanks again jmcilhinney

Comment: One more thing. How would I reference each label during run time? Would I have to use a For loop then?

Comment: You would use a `For` or `For Each` loop to access each `TabPage` and then, inside the loop, access the `Label` for the current `TabPage` by indexing the `Controls` collection. Alternatively, keep a separate `List(Of Label)` that you add the `label` controls to as well and loop over it.

Comment: You never fail me sir. Thanks a million